# graphics and includgraphics bb

Tags: graphics, bounding-box

I am producing a book which starts:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{book}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{graphicx}          % Packages to allow inclusion of graphics
\usepackage{color}             % For creating coloured text and background
\usepackage{hyperref}          % For creating hyperlinks in cross references
\usepackage{alltt}
...
```

then I have

```
\includegraphics*[bb 20 20 302 334,width=3.15cm,clip]{inserts/OCT1.pdf}
```

but this fails:

```
! Package keyval Error: bb 20 20 302 334 undefined.
```

Why?

Answer (score 4):

You need `bb=20 20 302 334`, since `bb` (short for `b`ounding `b`ox) uses the key-value syntax, as in `<key>=<value>`.

Some keys don't need a value, or assumes a default value if none is supplied. Not in this case.

Comment: A default would not help here as you _need_ a value of some sort